# Why doesn't IDictionary<TKey, TValue> implement IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>?

Tags: c#, dictionary, readonly-collection

I noticed that [Dictionary Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) implements `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` as well as `IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

However [IDictionary Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea(v=vs.110).aspx) does not implement `IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

This means that if my class has an `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, and I need to pass an `IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>` I ought to create an adapter for this, or use a different work around.

IMHO every class that has the functionality of an `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` also has the functionality of an `IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

Did they simply forget to implement it, or are there really meaningful classes that implement `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` that can't have a meaningful implementations of `IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>`?

Comment: Shortly - for backward compatibility. `IReadOnlyXyz` interfaces are introduced later, so making the existing interfaces "inherit" from them (even if it's possible) would be a breaking change.

Comment: Would it be a breaking change if IReadOnlyDictionary was implemented explicitly?

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse - There's no implementation on an interface so it can't be implemented, explicitly or implicitly.

Comment: You don't need an adapter, you can use a simple cast: `         private IDictionary<int, string> _Dictionary= new Dictionary<int, string>(); `
 `        public IReadOnlyDictionary<int, string> TheDictionary => (IReadOnlyDictionary<int, string>)_Dictionary; `

Comment: Bernhard: your examle works because in your excample the actual object that _Dictionary refers to also implements `IReadOnlyDictionary<int, string>`. However, if I get an object of a class that implements `IDictionary<int, string>`, I can't be certain that the object also implements the `IReadOnlyDictionary<int, string>`. If it doesn't, I get an `InvalidCastException` when trying to cast. For those situations I still need an adapter